# Wifi unable to find connections on Windows 8 laptop

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-8, laptop

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop running Windows 8. For a while now I've been having a chronic problem where I come back to the laptop after leaving it idle for a while (usually overnight) to find that my network is disabled. I click the network icon but it says "No networks found" and the option to start and stop Wifi doesn't exist. Sometimes the problem manifests itself in a different way, where after finding the internet to be disabled, I click on the Network icon, but nothing appears, and no matter how long I wait, the interface never comes up. Restarting the laptop always fixes the problem though (in both manifestations).

This is the list of things I've tried before restarting:

Disabling/enabling Airplane mode
Disabling/enabling various network adapters and devices (sometimes this works, but not always)
Automatic troubleshooting of network problems

If anyone has any idea of what I can do so that I don't have to restart every time this problem comes up, I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if this is a fix, but worth a try: Go to: Device manager > Network adaptors > right-click on your wireless chipset > Properties > Power management > Untick "allow computer to turn off..." Please reply if this works.

Comment: I already have that unchecked actually, and I also disabled and re-enabled that device multiple times.

Comment: Are you sure disable and re-enabling the NIC doesn't always work to resolve?

Comment: It only works about half of the time. The only thing that always works is restarting.

Comment: Update th the BIOS and drivers from Dell's website. That is pretty much always the go to advice for something like this. Could be a known issue, especially surrounding the wifi switch. If the wifi switch is mechanical you could also have a problem there.